# Is the Gmail "Map this" feature available in API?

Tags: google-maps, google-api

Does anybody know Google provides the Gmail "Map this" feature is available with API. I researched a lot but didn't find the desired result. I want the Google API on which I give the string message:

```
BREA PROBLEM F:830 N MAIN ST 46, MT ANGEL:R454,
MED23:MAP-2530C:57YOF/ C/DIFFB  BEE STING:BAVARIAN VILLAGE    503 845-2586::
```

And Google returns the result as it would for the "Map this" feature:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?q=830+N+MAIN+ST+MT+ANGEL,+OR&oi=gmail
```

Here is the image to better understand my question:

[image: Gmail "Map this" screenshot]

Comment: The answers help at all?

Comment: Actually i know how to use google API for any address, I mean if i know `830 N MAIN ST MT ANGEL, OR` is address, i can use google api to get coordinates, My question is how do i know `830 N MAIN ST MT ANGEL, OR` is a address in complete message `BREA PROBLEM F:830 N MAIN ST 46, MT ANGEL:R454,
MED23:MAP-2530C:57YOF/ C/DIFFB  BEE STING:BAVARIAN VILLAGE    503 845-2586::`? How google detect in message that?

Answer (score 2):

### Google Maps API

You can accomplish the "Map this" functionaliy by utilizing the [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/). More precisely, you are trying to [geocode a given address](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#Geocoding):

> **Geocoding** is the process of converting addresses (like "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA") into geographic coordinates
>   (like latitude 37.423021 and longitude -122.083739), which you can use
>   to place markers or position the map.

You can find a simple live geocoding example here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple

Ultimately, it reads that you are after the URL. There doesn't appear to be an explicit return from the API request that will provide the URL. You can easily create the URL, however, if you receive the following [status code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingStatusCodes) from the request:

```
google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK indicates that the geocode was successful.
```

### Manual URL Creation

Alternatively, you could create the URL with the given address. For example, if the given address is 1500 Red Oak Drive, concatenate that string to `http://maps.google.com/maps?q=` and Google Maps will resolve to a match or display possible matches.

Here are some ficitous addresses I made up. The first actually exists and GMaps located it. The second doesn't and GMapgs provided some possible matches.

- http://maps.google.com/maps?q=2301+Juniper+lane
- http://maps.google.com/maps?q=111+One+Drive

### Static Maps API V2 Developer Guide

The [Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) may also give you ideas on how to construct a URL based on a given address.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply convert your address to google lang and latitude address:

There are 2 steps for best and assured manual URL creation

**Step 1:**
Get lat and lang of your address
Use the LocationManager.

```java
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
double longitude = location.getLongitude();
double latitude = location.getLatitude();
The call to getLastKnownLocation() doesn't block - which means it will return null if no position is currently available - so you probably want to have a look at passing a LocationListener to the requestLocationUpdates() method instead, which will give you asynchronous updates of your location.

private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }
}

lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 10, locationListener);
You'll need to give your application the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission if you want to use GPS.

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
You may also want to add the ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission for when GPS isn't available and select your location provider with the getBestProvider() method.
```

**Step 2 :**
Insert Lang and lat in google url
something like this

```
String url = "https://www.google.co.in/maps/place/"+ Langitude +","+ Lattitude;
```

You can do whatever you like with this url like giving it to webview or opening it google maps. Or enabling it with google embedded maps, Or simply send this string as a mail